# string[].Contains does not find a match even if the text is in the array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have put displays into my program, and can clearly see that the string being searched for is present.

Is it possible that there are 'invisible' characters preventing this from working?

```
    var items = new List<string>(currComponent.Split(new string[] 
    { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
    string feedback = string.Empty;
                foreach (string i in items)
                {
                    feedback += i + ". ";
                }
                ScriptingObject.WriteLogMessage
                 ("feedback:" + feedback + "<EOF>", true);
   if (items.Contains(attributeDescription))
```

The result of the display shows that the variable feedback contains the phrase 'Flue',
but **`items.Contains("Flue")`** does not find it.

```
Message: Status message: 2015-01-09 10:36:18 | feedback:_ ,. Boiler Flue Type. 
Boiler make. Boiler Model. Gas Appliance Safety Protector. __.. . <EOF>

Next message: unable to process an Update Location record ...because of error:
item Flue not found .
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because string in `items` is not `"Flue"` but `"Boiler Flue Type"` and `List.Contains()` searches for an exact match, remember you're calling `List.Contains()` not `String.Contains()`.

Note that there is a simpler way to join your strings:

```
string feedback = String.Join(". ", items);
```

With LINQ you may use this:

```
if (items.Any(x => x.Contains(attributeDescription))) { }
```

If you do not explicitly need a `List<string>` you may also keep `String.Split()` return type (`string[]`), to put all together:

```
var items = currComponent.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None);

ScriptingObject.WriteLogMessage("feedback: " 
    + String.Join(". ", items)
    + "<EOF>", true);

if (items.Any(x => x.Contains(attributeDescription))) {
}
```

Comment: I am still getting problems with this, where it is not finding text it is clearly writing to a log. The data concerned is coming from a Screen Grab. Is it possible that it contains invisible or unprintable characters, which is preventing the .contains working?

Comment: For _plain ASCII words_ (!!!) like "Boiler" and working with System.String I cannot think about any character encoding issue. Try to post also your new code...